# How to make Text thick and fill in with a color using css,and change color onhover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to increase the width of a text.I am not trying to make it bold.I am trying to keep the inside of the text empty.My idea is to fill the text with a color,and ,onhover change the color.

Here is a picture of what i am trying to accomplish:

http://img.ctrlv.in/50eee77779a5b.jpg

The issue is that I cant find a way how to increase text width using css.(i found it via javascript,but then the  text assumes properties of an image)(and hence onhover effect is not possible)(I found a way to increase font width using javascript in a w3schools tutorial here

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_text2)

I am looking for a html solution(not canvas)

I know there is a shortcut in CSS3/HTML 5 to achieve this effect,but not able to recollect/search sites where i saw the effect.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you looking for canvas or css/html solution? (your link points to a canvas example)

Comment: i am looking for a css/html solution.i just wanted to show the link as it shows how to make text thick.

Answer (score 0):

May not be perfect but not sure of a css selector that can increase letter width, you could try something like:

```
a:hover {
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    color: #07C;
}
```

This increases distance between letters, also use css rather than jquery for hover event, its easier!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you actually want to stroke the text. The width of the font can stay the same so long as the stroke happens outside the boundaries of the text, right?
Well, [CSS Tricks has an article](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) which talks about stroking text using webkit-text-stroke and/or text-shadow. An example is given [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/TextStroke/).

So, you would end up with something like:

```
/* CSS from tutorial */
.stroke {
  /* WebKit (Safari/Chrome) Only */
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;

  /* If we weren't using text-shadow, we'd set a fallback color
     and use this to set color instead
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white; */

  color: white;

  text-shadow:
    3px 3px 0 #000,
    /* Simulated effect for Firefox and Opera
       and nice enhancement for WebKit */
   -1px -1px 0 #000,  
    1px -1px 0 #000,
   -1px  1px 0 #000,
    1px  1px 0 #000;
}

/* The colour changing bit - added by me */
.stroke:hover {
   color:blue;
}
```